# jQuery Ready code not executing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code in my `_Layout.cshtml`, targeted at a view once removed, through a layout nested one level below `_Layout.cshtml`.

```
<title>@ViewBag.PageTitle</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@Url.Content("~/Images/favicon.png")" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Blueprint/screen.css")" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Blueprint/print.css")" media="print" />
@Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.simple.css"))
@RenderSection("MainBodyStyling", false)
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        //$("iframe").width($("iframe").contents().find("table").width());
    });
</script>
```

I cannot get the jQuery code to execute, in Chrome or Firefox 5.0, even just the debugger call.  This is with jQuery 1.4.4, inside an MVC3 project.  The code works when I paste it into both Firebug and Chrome JS consoles, so I know the code itself is not at fault.

**CORRECTION:**  I added the erroneous document with quotes as a last ditch attempt.  I had tried my default (I'm quite used to working with jQuery), `$(function () {` syntax, with no difference.  The real problem is not my syntax, but correct code not executing.  I have removed the quotes with no difference at all.

**ADDENDUM:**  If I put a breakpoint on the `debugger` line, the code stops at the breakpoint in the Chrome console.  I have no idea what this is about.

Comment: Are there any syntax errors on the page?  A syntax error in another part of the page (or in jQuery itself) could cause the ready event not to fire.

Comment: @Jab, I have no other code on the page, and I doubt Telerik or Microsoft code would introduce errors of such impact.

Comment: @profK Are you using the telerik script registrar? I know you dont show it above but thought I work ask since this auto includes jquery by default and may be causing a conflict with two copies of jq.

Comment: @redsquare, I am, thanks.  I don't know what was wrong, but the behaviour has mysteriously vanished, and all is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your scripts at the bottom of the document just before the closing body tag. This is non blocking and avoids any need for doc ready blocks. Double win.

[Further reading](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/) from Yahoo and [here](http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/) by Dave Ward.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use quotes around `document`.

```
$(document).ready(function () { });
```

or better yet, just pass your handler function directly into the jQuery method (its an alias for `ready`):

```
$(function () { });
```

Answer (score 4):

`document` should be without quotes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    debugger;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a string "document" in the selector it needs to be the document object

```
$(document).ready();
```

Answer (score 1):

as already stated, `document` shouldn't have quotes. To avoid this, you can do

```
$(function() {
    debugger;
});
```

instead to define a ready callback

Answer (score 0):

jquery-1.4.4.min.js is not included in the scripts folder, so it can not be used.

I have replaced it with jquery-1.5.1.min.js and the problem was solved.